# How to create patch for Kohana?

Tags: kohana, redmine, patch

I've found a bug at Kohana couple hours ago and fixed it. After that I found a [ticket at Redmine describing same issue](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/4301). Now I want to create patch for the bug but I dont know how to do this. Could anyone give an advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git diff > diff.patch`

A better way would be to fork the repository on github, commit your change, then send a pull request.